# Я написал программу на python и с помощью pyinstaller превратил её в exe файл. Будет ли он работать на windows 7, если я использую версию 3.9.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7, pyinstaller, exe

Допустим, у меня есть python версии 3.9.5, который не поддерживается на windows 7. Я написал программу в py файле и с помощью pyinstaller превратил этот файл в exe. Будет ли работать exe файл на windows 7? Так как у меня нет компьютера с windows 7, проверить я это не могу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyInstaller не компилирует код, а просто заворачивает в exe файл интерпретатор Python и вашу программу. Если версия интерпретатора не поддерживает систему, на которой собираетесь запускать, то и exe на этой системе не запустится.

Python 3.9 не поддерживает Windows 7. Поддерживаемые версии можно посмотреть на [странице скачивания python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/), например:

- "Note that Python 3.9.6 cannot be used on Windows 7 or earlier." - версия Python 3.9.6 не может использоваться на Windows 7 и более ранних версиях
- "Note that Python 3.8.11 cannot be used on Windows XP or earlier." - аналогично, Python 3.8.11 не может использоваться на WinXP и более ранних версиях.

Если вдруг нужна будет поддержка Windows XP - используйте Python 3.4

Что еще нужно учитывать:

- Для версий Python 3.5 и выше на "целевом" компьютере возможно потребуется установить дополнительные обновления системы (без нужного обновления будет кидать ошибки, что отсутствуют библиотеки типа `api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll` и с другими подобными именами). В целом, Python до версии 3.4 (включительно) более "неприхотлив".
- Экзешник, собранный PyInstaller на 64-битной версии Python, не запустится на 32-битной операционной системе. Если нужна поддержка 32-битных систем - собирайте на 32-битной версии Python, тогда будет работать и на 32-битных, и на 64-битных системах (два отдельных экзешника делать не нужно, достаточно одного 32-битного).

> Так как у меня нет компьютера с windows 7, проверить я это не могу.

Для тестирования работоспособности полученного экзешника можно установить виртуальную машину (я обычно использую [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org)) с нужной операционной системой. Отдельный компьютер для этого не нужен.