# Exe скомпилирован на WIn x64 не работает на х32

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

Есть некий код написан на Python, модули которые использую tkinter, pyautogui, os, shutil, platform. Самый обрезанный его аналог (просто окно tkintera с кнопками и тд)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def windows():
    global win_bit
    os_sys = platform.architecture()
    if '64bit' in os_sys:
        win_bit = 64
    elif '32bit' in os_sys:
        win_bit = 32
windows()

root = tk.Tk()

def mainwindow():
    root.geometry('600x400+200+100')
    root.title('Window_main')
    but1 = tk.Button(root, text='Ок', command = secondwindow)
    but1.place(x=60, y=30)


def secondwindow():
    window2 = tk.Toplevel()
    window2.geometry('600x400+200+100')
    window2.title('Window_2')

    frame_top = tk.Frame(window2, bd=5)
    frame_top.place(x =20 , y = 40, relheight = 0.25, relwidth = 0.25)

    but2 = tk.Button(window2, text='Ок', command=output_data)
    but2.place(x=60, y=30)

    global entry
    entry = tk.StringVar()
    entry_form = tk.Entry(frame_top, textvariable=entry, font='arial 12', bg='thistle1')
    entry_form.place(x=40, y=10, width=60, height=20)

def output_data():
    serv = entry.get()
    print(serv)




mainwindow()

root.mainloop()
```

Суть не в коде, суть когда через Pyinstaller компилируешь код, на Винде х64 он работает, на х32 -нет. Читал что он упаковывает с собой текущий питон. Если он 64, на 32 работать не будет. Но конкретных простых решений не нашел. Чем посоветуете компилить дабы работало на всех бит-платформах?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вариант... попробовать поставить х32 питон, отдельно, и компилить через него.

Comment: @Gh0sTG0 ну это в общем-то единственный вариант

Comment: Спасибо за варинат, конечно попробую, но не совсем то что хотелось. Хотелось бы один файл под все бит. Так как в коде есть такой кусок, который определяет битность и исполняет разные скрипты под разные битности. Добавил в код выше.

Comment: Проверка внутри питон кода не поможет. Проблема в том, что сам 64 битный интерпретатор упакованый pyinstaller-ом в exe не может выполнятся на 32 битной системе. А чтоб иметь один exe нужно чтоб он был 32 битным, на 64 битной системе он будет работать.

Comment: "Хотелось бы один файл под все бит." - делайте 32-битный файл, он будет работать и на 32-битной, и на 64-битной Windows

Comment: Написал подробный ответ здесь, отдельно написал там про битность: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1319773/1365

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю - никак. Вам нужно компилировать отдельно для 32 и 64 бит. Готов ответить на уточняющие вопросы. Подскажите я смог Вам помочь?

Comment: Достаточно 32-битного экзешника, он будет работать и на 64-битной системе. Про это в комментариях к вопросу писали.

Comment: Есть уточняющий вопрос. Если у меня уже стоит python и pycharm на х64, как я могу себе установить еще одну версию? И почитав, пишут новых версий пайчарма х32 не выпускают? последняя версия 2018 года. (поставил себе на виртуалку вин 7 на х32бит + пайчарм, перекинул проекты сделаные на рабочем пк, начал устанавливать модули которые в проекте используются (tkinter, pywinauto, time, shutil) начали вылезать куча ошибок по типу обновите пайчарм..

Comment: Вам нужно установить ещё одну версию пайчарма?

Comment: @ВалераФедотов, не нужна еще одна версия пайчарма, нужна только еще одна (32-битная) версия Python, на том же компе с 64-битной системой, без всяких виртуалок.